# pivpn install - fails to install iptables-persistent

Tags: pi-4, apt, vpn, iptables

Installation of pivpn fails due to missing iptables-persistent. Command (run as root) is

```
curl -L https://install.pivpn.io | bash
```

and result is

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   162  100   162    0     0    131      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   131
100 83088  100 83088    0     0  51479      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 51479
:::
::: You are root.
::: Hostname length OK
::: Verifying free disk space...
:::
::: Checking apt-get for upgraded packages.... done!
:::
::: Your system is up to date! Continuing with PiVPN installation...
:::    Checking for git... already installed!
:::    Checking for tar... already installed!
:::    Checking for wget... already installed!
:::    Checking for curl... already installed!
:::    Checking for grep... already installed!
:::    Checking for dnsutils... already installed!
:::    Checking for whiptail... already installed!
:::    Checking for net-tools... already installed!
:::    Checking for bsdmainutils... already installed!
:::    Checking for dhcpcd5... already installed!
:::    Checking for iptables-persistent... not installed!
:::    Failed to install iptables-persistent!
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  netfilter-persistent
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  iptables-persistent netfilter-persistent
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 21.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 80.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf netfilter-persistent all 1.0.11
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf iptables-persistent all 1.0.11
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/i/iptables-persistent/netfilter-persistent_1.0.11_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/i/iptables-persistent/iptables-persistent_1.0.11_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Running

```
apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

By itself has the same result, and its quite right; iptables-persistent_1.0.11_all.deb doesn't exist at that location. (iptables-persistent_1.0.14_all.deb does, though). Is there a config problem in the repository?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your apt cache is not up to date. Did you run `apt update` before trying to install? Please update your question with relevant info.

Comment: Certainly did, several times. In fact the automated installation also runs it itself as you can see from the output.

Comment: It's working today. Looks like someone had only half updated the repository yesterday.